# Simple vector initialization in C++11 returns weird error

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, g++

Compiling this piece of code:

```
#include <vector>

long long sumOfMedians(int seed, int mul, int add, int N, int K)
{
  std::vector<int> nos{N+2,0};
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
      if(i == 0)
    nos[i] = seed;
      else
    nos[i] = (nos[i-1]*mul + add)%65536;
    }
}

int main()
{
  sumOfMedians(3,1,1,10,3);
  return 0;
}
```

causes an error

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006e8010 ***
[2]    31743 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

While slightly changing the vector initialization line (line 5 in previous code) to (line 5,6 in new code)

```
#include <vector>

long long sumOfMedians(int seed, int mul, int add, int N, int K)
{
  std::vector<int> nos;
  nos.resize(N+2,0);
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
      if(i == 0)
    nos[i] = seed;
      else
    nos[i] = (nos[i-1]*mul + add)%65536;
    }
}

int main()
{
  sumOfMedians(3,1,1,10,3);
  return 0;
}
```

Causes it to compile successfully. What gives?

g++ parameter: -std=c++11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `vector`, brace-initialisation initialises the vector contents to the contents of the initialiser list, so

```
std::vector<int> nos{N+2,0};
```

initialises it to a size of 2, with elements `N+2` and `0`. This uses the constructor that takes a single parameter of type `std::initializer_list`.

Changing the braces to parentheses causes it to instead use the two-argument constructor that specifies the size and initial value for all elements. That's what you want here; although you could leave out the second argument since elements are zero-initialised by default.

Answer (score 7):

List-initialisation for vectors is a way to provide a list of initial elements. It is *not* the same as providing constructor arguments.

That's because [`std::vector<T>` has a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which is the best match when you use `{x,y,..,z}`:

> `[C++11: 8.5.4/2]:` A constructor is an *initializer-list constructor* if its first parameter is of type `std::initializer_list<E>` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list<E>` for some type `E`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6). *[ Note:* **Initializer-list constructors are favored over other constructors in list-initialization (13.3.1.7).** *—end note ]* The template `std::initializer_list` is not predefined; if the header `<initializer_list>` is not included prior to a use of `std::initializer_list` — even an implicit use in which the type is not named (7.1.6.4) — the program is ill-formed.
>
> `[C++11: 13.3.1.7/1]:` When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - **Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.**
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

So:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

There are seven elements in this vector.

Likewise:

```
std::vector<int> nos{N+2, 0};
```

There are two elements in this vector; the first one has value `N+2`, and the second has value `0`. Your subsequent looping to `N`, since `N` in your case is 10, causes memory corruption.

If you instead write the following:

```
std::vector<int> nos(N+2, 0);
```

then you use the expected vector constructor, which functions similarly to `std::vector::resize`.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing a **size-2 vector** with [brace-initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) (vector has a constructor which accepts `std::initializer_list<int>`)

```
std::vector<int> nos{ N + 2, 0 };
```

and afterwards asking for the index 2 (**out-of-range**):

```
nos[2] = (nos[2 - 1] * mul + add) % 65536;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write:

```
  std::vector<int> nos(N+2,0);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what the second example in the question says. The question is, why?